# LEFT JOIN ON COALESCE(a, b, c) - very strange behavior

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, coalesce

I have encountered very strange behavior of my query and I wasted a lot of time to understand what causes it, in vane. So I am asking for your help.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN front_table ON front_table.pk = main_table.fk_front_table
LEFT JOIN info_table ON info_table.pk = front_table.fk_info_table
LEFT JOIN key_table ON key_table.pk = COALESCE(info_table.fk_key_table, front_table.fk_key_table_1, front_table.fk_key_table_2)
LEFT JOIN side_table ON side_table.fk_front_table = front_table.pk
WHERE side_table.pk = (SELECT MAX(pk) FROM side_table WHERE fk_front_table = front_table.pk)
OR side_table.pk IS NULL
```

Seems like a simple join query, with coalesce, I've used this technique before(not too many times) and it worked right.

In this query I don't ever get nulls for side_table.pk. If I remove coalesce or just don't use key_table, then the query returns rows with many null side_table.pk, but if I add coalesce join, I can't get those nulls.

It seems key_table and side_table don't have anything in common, but the result is so weird.

Also, when I don't use side_table and WHERE clause, the count(*) result with coalesce and without differs, but I can't see any pattern in rows missing, it seems random!

Real query:

```
SELECT ECHANGE.EXC_AUTO_KEY, STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STR_AUTO_KEY FROM EXCHANGE
LEFT JOIN WO_BOM ON WO_BOM.WOB_AUTO_KEY = EXCHANGE.WOB_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN VIEW_WO_SUB ON VIEW_WO_SUB.WOO_AUTO_KEY = WO_BOM.WOO_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN STOCK stock3 ON stock3.STM_AUTO_KEY = EXCHANGE.STM_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN STOCK stock2 ON stock2.STM_AUTO_KEY = EXCHANGE.ORIG_STM
LEFT JOIN CONSIGNMENT_CODES con2 ON con2.CNC_AUTO_KEY = stock2.CNC_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN CONSIGNMENT_CODES con3 ON con3.CNC_AUTO_KEY = stock3.CNC_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN CI_UTL ON CI_UTL.CUT_AUTO_KEY = EXCHANGE.CUT_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN PART_CONDITION_CODES pcc2 ON pcc2.PCC_AUTO_KEY = stock2.PCC_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN PART_CONDITION_CODES pcc3 ON pcc3.PCC_AUTO_KEY = stock3.PCC_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN STOCK_RESERVATIONS ON STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STM_AUTO_KEY = stock3.STM_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE wh2 ON wh2.WHS_AUTO_KEY = stock2.WHS_ORIGINAL
LEFT JOIN SM_HISTORY ON (SM_HISTORY.STM_AUTO_KEY = EXCHANGE.ORIG_STM AND SM_HISTORY.WOB_REF = EXCHANGE.WOB_AUTO_KEY)
LEFT JOIN RC_DETAIL ON stock3.RCD_AUTO_KEY = RC_DETAIL.RCD_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN RC_HEADER ON RC_HEADER.RCH_AUTO_KEY = RC_DETAIL.RCH_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE wh3 ON wh3.WHS_AUTO_KEY = COALESCE(RC_DETAIL.WHS_AUTO_KEY, stock3.WHS_ORIGINAL, stock3.WHS_AUTO_KEY)
WHERE STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STR_AUTO_KEY = (SELECT MAX(STR_AUTO_KEY) FROM STOCK_RESERVATIONS WHERE STM_AUTO_KEY = stock3.STM_AUTO_KEY)
OR STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STR_AUTO_KEY IS NULL
```

Removing LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE wh3 gives me about unique EXC_AUTO_KEY values with a lot of NULL STR_AUTO_KEY, while leaving this row removes all NULL STR_AUTO_KEY.

I recreated simple tables with numbers with the same structure and query works without any problems o.0

Comment: I suspect you need to clarify the problem with some sample data that shows what you think goes wrong.

Comment: I assume you mean that without the condition in the `where` clause you never get `NULL` values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Clearly there is non-minimal code/data here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling `COALESCE` is acting as a `REQUIRED` flag for the joined table, hence shooting the `LEFT JOIN` to become an `INNER JOIN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM main_table
  LEFT JOIN front_table ON front_table.pk = main_table.fk_front_table
  LEFT JOIN info_table ON info_table.pk = front_table.fk_info_table
  LEFT JOIN key_table ON key_table.pk = NVL(info_table.fk_key_table, NVL(front_table.fk_key_table_1, front_table.fk_key_table_2))
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT fk_, MAX(pk) as pk FROM side_table GROUP BY fk_) st ON st.fk_ = front_table.pk
```

`NVL` might behave just the same though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but NVL behaves the same, tried it also. Ill have a lot more to say soon, trying to get data.

Comment: Just curious to why do you need to `COUNT(*)` that query. I suppose this is a modified query for SO but as it stands, the COUNT is an issue to resolve this problem. It would be good to see the original query

Comment: I recreated simple tablws with numbers with this structure and this query works perfectly fine, so I guess something is in the data? I added original query, quite unreadable, but supposed to be a draft :)

Comment: So far I got this: If I put coalesce join before side_table join which is included in where subquery - everything works. If I split the OR clause into two different subquery, they both give correct results separately. If I don't use info_table in coalesce - it works.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't followup on this. This is a very interesting subject so please share your solution if you find any, however I don't have the necessary time to give you a hand on this as I've been very occupied.

Comment: The solution is not to use the VIEW join, because joining tables with views that are based on those tables causes results be incorrect sometimes. As far as I know it's a little bit random, but more likely experienced users would be able to explain and predict such outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I undertood what was the problem (not entirely though): there is a LEFT JOIN VIEW_WO_SUB in original query, 3rd line. It causes this query to act in a weird way.

When I replaced the view with the other table which contained the information I needed, the query started returning right results.

Basically, with this view join, NVL, COALESCE or CASE join with combination of certain arguments did not work along with OR clause in WHERE subquery, all rest was fine. ALthough, I could get the query to work with this view join, by changing the order of joined tables, I had to place table participating in where subquery to the bottom.